# Averaging different values in the same matrix and storing them in a different matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, average

So I'm trying to write a code that will fetch me a certain integer N times and store that integer in a 1xN vector matrix call temp. That part of the code works.
What I want to do is go through that iteration M times, and every time the code goes for an iteration, I want it to compute the Average of temp and store it at index M in the new matrix.

For example: assume N = 3 and M = 3.

> First iteration at N = 3, M = 1: temp holds [1 1 1] whose average is 1.
>   Second iteration at N = 3, M = 2: temp holds [2 2 2] whose average is 2.
>   Third iteration at N = 3, M = 3: temp holds [3 3 3] whose average is 3.
>   At this point, the new matrix should hold [1 2 3] namely the average of the first, second and third iteration respectively.
>   Here is the code I've written

```
function [  ] = Plotter( N,M )
temp = zeros(N);
final = zeros(M);

for X = 1:M
    for i = 1:N
        temp(i) = %Calls a method to get these numbers
    end
    final(X) = mean(temp);
end
```

Comment: Can you give us better example data? It's very unclear what you want based on your over-simplified examples. As you have it you don't need a mean since everything is the *same number* and the mean is simply *that* number

Comment: "... and store that integer in a 1xN vector matrix call temp." But you are initializing `temp` as an NxN matrix (and `final` as MxM). Use `temp = zeros(1, N); final = zeros(1, M);`